# I want to validate a textfield in a Java based app where I want to allow only comma separated digit from 0 to 9

Tags: java, regex

I want to validate a textfield in a Java based app where I want to allow only comma separated digit from 0 to 9.
for example
{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
regular expression that accept max 10 digit in any sequence.

Comment: Java or JavaScript? Choose one...

Comment: `for example {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} regular expression that accept max 10 digit in any sequence` - no it isn't

Comment: does it have to be regex?

Comment: @NishanthMatha a couple of minutes ago I was going to suggest an edit so that your comment would be `1,20` but based upon the lack of information in the question I am not sure

Comment: @NishanthMatha you regular expression will allow the digit like ,1, or 1, also.. but i want comma(,) should not present before or after the number and can we write regular expression that allow only uniq digit. for Example {1,2,3}= valid and {1,2,2} = invalid

Comment: then try this one: `^\d[\d,]{0,19}[^,]$`

Comment: but above regular expression is not allowing single digit. like when i am giving only 1 then it will fail

Comment: Please verify as to whether the opening and closing curly braces are mandatory

Comment: @NaveenGupta All the number (0-9) needs to be unique ?

Comment: @AshrafulIslam yes

Comment: @ScaryWombat curly braces not mandetory

Comment: Java is to JavaScript as Car is to Carpet :P So don't tag both unless it involves both :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're after plain regex you could try this:

`^\d[\d,]{0,18}[^,]$`

**Edit:**

After the requirement change. You can try this regex:

```
^(?:(([\d]),)(?!.*\2)){0,9}\d$
```

It will check for uniqure numbers

Regex explanation:

```
^                          - if starts with 
(([\d]),)                  - look for a digit followed by comma and capture the digit 
(?!.*\2)                   - don't allow any other characters or previously matched digits (`\2` matches the previous group which is digits matched in previous step)
(?:(([\d]),)(?!.*\2))       - don't capture the group (capture the entire string)
{0,9}                       - allow only 0-9 occurrences of previous match (9 chars for numbers and 9 chars for commas)
\d$                        - should end with a digit (10th digit)
```

Comment: needs to start and end with curly braces, also your solution accepts `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1`

Comment: @ScaryWombat I read the OP as " I want to allow only comma separated digit from 0 to 9". It's not clear at all what the OP means with the sentence after that. I don't think this question should be answered until the OP clarifies.

Comment: @ScaryWombat thanks for your comment, as far I understand the OP was just showing `{}` to implicate theat he wants a regex not the exact `{` to be matched by regex. And fort the second part where it allows 11 digits please see edit

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt As per OP's comments *Example {1,2,3}= valid and {1,2,2} = invalid* - **seems to be changing requirements as he goes**

Comment: hang on, I have asked for verification  - BUT looks like digits should be unique

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt  i forgot to mentioned that should accept only unique digit from 0 to 9. my mistake..

Comment: Thank you so much Nishanth.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Regex :

```
\{\d(,\d){0,9}\}
```

Demo : http://regexr.com/3esnc

Comment: originally upvoted but it looks like digits should be unique

Comment: above regular expression will not work for single digit